# Create an case insensitive apache alias

Tags: apache-http-server, alias

I am currently using Apache 2.4.4. Now, the problem is that when I am creating alias like

```
Alias /mysite "D:/MySite"
```

it doesn't work for `http://127.0.0.1/MySite`. So how can I make it case insensitive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AliasMatch?

```
AliasMatch (?i)^/mysite/(.*)$ D:/MySite/$1
```